# I want to be able to send an email via php to specific addresses depending on how a html form is filled

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, email

I have a small form requesting a call back which has optional departments.  I would like the php to send the request to different emails depending on which department is chosen.  I am struggling with the PHP and would very much like some help please.

Below is my latest attempt which sends the email to sales@domain.co.uk whatever us selected so it is my "if" statements that appear to be the problem in my php.

```
<form action="js/call.php" method="post"  class="contactForm">
                        
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" >
</div>


<div class="form-group col-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Contact Number">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-12">
<select id="department-chosen"  class="form-control" name="department-chosen" required>
<option hidden value="">Please select a department</option>
   <option value="sales">Bike Sales</option>
  <option value="service">Workshop</option>
  <option value="parts">Parts</option>
  <option value="clothing">Clothing / Accessories</option>
  

</select></div>




<div><input type="text" name="reference" id="reference"   tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" > </div>



                          <!-- START CAPTCHA -->

<br>


<div class="float-end"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-af1" name="text" value="Send">
          <i class="pe-1 fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Send</button>
</div> 
 </form>
```

```
<?php 
// if the reference field is not empty
if(!empty($_POST['reference'])) die();
// if the test field is empty
if(isset($_POST['reference']) && $_POST['test'] == ''){

if($_POST['department-chosen']  == 'sales') $to = "sales@domain.co.uk";
elseif($_POST['department-chosen']  == 'service') $to = "service@domain.co.uk";
elseif($_POST['department-chosen']  == 'parts') $to = "parts@domain.co.uk";
else $to = "clothing@domain.co.uk";

             
 $from = $_REQUEST['phone'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
 $subject = "Call back requested from website"; 
 
 $fields = array(); 
 $fields["name"] = "Name";
 $fields["phone"] = "Phone"; 
 $fields["department-chosen"] = "Department"; 
 $fields["reference"] = "reference";
 

 $body = "We have received the following 'call back' request:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 
 
 

 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body); 
 if($send) 
 {header( "Location: https://www.domain.co.uk/thankyou.htm" );} 
 
 
 
 
 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify service@domain.co.uk"; } 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Put `var_dump($_POST);` just before your `if($_POST['department-chosen']  == 'sales')...` line so you can see what's actually in the POSTed data, and then see if your `if` statements are looking at the right thing.

Comment: If I knew how to do that I would but all that is a little beyond me sorry  :/

Comment: know how to do what? Literally all I want is that you just write that line of code where I told you to, and then show us what it outputs.

Comment: P.S. `all that is a little beyond me`...why? Debugging is a basic skill which every programmer needs to start learning almost as soon as they write their first program. I am continually astonished when I look at questions on this site that people attempt to write reasonably complex programs seemingly without having understood (or apparently even attempted to find out) anything about how they might go about testing them or detecting errors in them. It's like being a plumber who can install a pipe but has no idea what to do if it leaks...it's not a sustainable existence!

Comment: Here are some useful guides: https://phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#debugging, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/  . You can find similar for JavaScript too, as that's usually applicable for web developers (but isn't relevant in this specific case as far as I can see).

Comment: I would just like to say we all have to start somewhere and all I was asking was if my coding was correct. I ran it live and it gave me this.....array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Jan Cooper" ["phone"]=> string(11) "07725199202" ["department-chosen"]=> string(8) "clothing" ["reference"]=> string(0) "" ["text"]=> string(4) "Send" }  I ran it in https://wtools.io/php-sandbox and it gave me nothing.

Comment: Use this code `$to = $_POST['department-chosen']."@domain.co.uk";` to determine the recipient address of the mail rather than several `if`. This code is possible because the department entered in the `value` of your `<select>` corresponds exactly to the department used in the email. This code assumes of course that a department is necessarily selected...

Comment: `all I was asking was if my coding was correct`...that's what debugging is for, in order to determine that! `we all have to start somewhere`...yes, absolutely, but learning to debug is a key part of the starting process...it's unclear how you've got to the point of designing a whole HTML form and having moderately complex `if/else` blocks etc etc without seemingly having got any info on the basics of actually testing your code.

Comment: Not sure what you did in the sandbox, but I made a demo here: https://3v4l.org/pQJIT (with simulated POST data naturally, since it can't accept those directly) and based on the var_dump info you provided (thanks!) it correctly chooses "clothing@domain.co.uk" as the email address and sets all the other variables as expected too. So it's a bit unclear how you're getting emails to the "sales" address instead, based on this scenario.

Comment: You might be wise to do what I've done at the end of the demo, and just print out all the variables as well as sending the email, so then you can see what PHP actually provided to the mailserver in that particular execution of the script.

Comment: Thank you very much all this has been an education and I do appreciate it very much- I will endeavour to educate myself better -  Juan's suggestion has worked too in the test so my initial problem is now solved :)